# After recent W10 upgrade the printing of pdf files is broken

Tags: printing, adobe

This is not directly related to LaTeX issues, however after recent (automatically) upgrade of Windows 10 OS, the printing of pdf files generated by pdfLaTeX from Acrobat Reader DC is broken. Instead of text on pages are black lines. Chapter and section titles and partly images are normally visible.

Do anyone have experience with this problem? I use HP LaseJet P2055d printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, be it of Windows 10 or Acrobat, see here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2210106

That printing is such a trouble in the year 2016.

Comment: Thank you very much for info. I hope, that this will be fixed soon. printing from Sumatra is very slow and annoying.